# Multiple Database Projects

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a set of visual studio 2010 database projects that depend upon each other. I am able to build the lowest level project script, and then build my child scripts separately after that. When I attempt to upgrade these to visual studio 2013, building the child projects puts the entire schema from the parent inside of the child script as well. Is there a way to avoid this behavior? Or is there a better pattern for maintaining this type of setup?